# Why am I getting "__call__: missing one positional argument", when I pass the correct number of arguments?

Tags: python, class, call

I am getting the following pytest error:

```
@pytest.fixture
    def mts_parser():
        """MTS parser fixture
        """
        mts = exchanges.get("MTS.CASH", db_write=False, filename='bondreference_20171023.txt')
>       mts.get_subparser()(mts, b'')
E       TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'

tests/unit/exchanges/mts/test_parser.py:27: TypeError
_________________________________ ERROR at setup of TestMTSParser.test_get_update_type_cancel[6-False-6-0]
```

In fact pytest is failing in a number of tests relating to this error:

```
ERROR tests/unit/exchanges/mts/test_parser.py::TestMTSParser::test_get_update_type_add[0-0-False-0-200-False] - TypeError: __call__() miss...
ERROR tests/unit/exchanges/mts/test_parser.py::TestMTSParser::test_get_update_type_add[0-1-True-6-200-False] - TypeError: __call__() missi...
ERROR tests/unit/exchanges/mts/test_parser.py::TestMTSParser::test_get_update_type_add[0-0-False-17-200-True] - TypeError: __call__() miss...
ERROR tests/unit/exchanges/mts/test_parser.py::TestMTSParser::test_get_update_type_add[0-1-False-6-200-True] - TypeError: __call__() missi...
ERROR tests/unit/exchanges/mts/test_parser.py::TestMTSParser::test_get_update_type_add[0-0-False-18-100-True] - TypeError: __call__() miss...
ERROR tests/unit/exchanges/mts/test_parser.py::TestMTSParser::test_get_update_type_add[0-1-False-6-100-True] - TypeError: __call__() missi...
ERROR tests/unit/exchanges/mts/test_parser.py::TestMTSParser::test_parse_fills[True-119.2--.306] - TypeError: __call__() missing 1 require...
ERROR tests/unit/exchanges/mts/test_parser.py::TestMTSParser::test_parse_fills[True-5-.] - TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positi...
ERROR tests/unit/exchanges/mts/test_parser.py::TestMTSParser::test_parse_fills[False-119.2--.306] - TypeError: __call__() missing 1 requir...
ERROR tests/unit/exchanges/mts/test_parser.py::TestMTSParser::test_parse_fills[False-5-.] - TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required posit...
ERROR tests/unit/exchanges/mts/test_parser.py::TestMTSParser::test_parse_orders - TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argu...
ERROR tests/unit/exchanges/mts/test_parser.py::TestMTSParser::test_parse_orders_bad_quantity - TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required po...
ERROR tests/unit/exchanges/mts/test_parser.py::TestMTSParser::test_get_isin[ES00000123B9] - TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required posit...
ERROR tests/unit/exchanges/mts/test_parser.py::TestMTSParser::test_get_isin[DE0001135408] - TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required posit...
ERROR tests/unit/exchanges/mts/test_parser.py::TestMTSParser::test_get_isin[DE0001104719] - TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required posit...
ERROR tests/unit/exchanges/mts/test_parser.py::TestMTSParser::test_get_isin[HU0000402730] - TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required posit...
```

Here is the aforementioned `__call__` function that is causing the failed test (it is worth noting that I recently added `context` below:

```
class Subparser:
    def __call__(self, obj, data, context):
        self.parser = obj
        self.logger = obj.logger
        self.parse_er_data(data, context)
```

I am trying to understand what is causing this error- is it because the different functions that are calling on `dunder call` are missing this extra `context` argument? Or have I added `context` wrongly to the `dunder call` function above?

Do let me know if more information is required!

The aforementioned `context` comes from the following:

```
class PacketContext:
    def __init__(self, capture_tstamp=None):
        self.capture_tstamp = capture_tstamp

class SubparserMixin:
    def __init__(self):
        self.context = PacketContext()
        self.subparsers = {}

    def on_packet(self, packet):
        self.context.capture_tstamp = packet.capture_timestamp
        self.parse_er_data(packet.payload, self.context)
```

Comment: You've defined `__call__()` to take three parameters (in addition to the implicit `self` parameter), you're calling instances of this class with only two parameters.  How were you expecting that to work?  Where is `context` supposed to get a value from?

Comment: Thanks Jason, how do you know I'm calling instances of this class with only two parameters- are you referring to parse_er_data(data, context)? Let me add to the bottom of the question where 'context' comes from.

Comment: Let me know if the above helps please! I've just added more details to the question

Comment: Literally where the arrow point to: this `>       mts.get_subparser()(mts, b'')` shows 2 parameters

Comment: Okay thank you! hmm I'm not even sure what I should add as the argument there. But I do see the issue now!

Comment: Hi guys, when I corrected the above, i got another error, can you please help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73055807/why-am-i-getting-typeerror-parse-er-data-takes-2-positional-arguments-but-3