# Why am I getting "TypeError: parse_er_data() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given" when I pass in the correct no. of args?

Tags: python, class

This is a follow on question from: [Why am I getting "__call__: missing one positional argument", when I pass the correct number of arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73055475/why-am-i-getting-call-missing-one-positional-argument-when-i-pass-the-co?noredirect=1#comment129028915_73055475)

After adding the extra parameter, the error in the link above was resolved, but it brought about a new error:

```
@pytest.fixture
    def mts_parser():
        """MTS parser fixture
        """
        mts = exchanges.get("MTS.CASH", db_write=False, filename='bondreference_20171023.txt')
>       mts.get_subparser()(mts, b'', 'context')

tests/unit/exchanges/mts/test_parser.py:27: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <exchanges.impl.mts.parser.MTSParser object at 0x7f7833257a00>, obj = Dataset MTS.CASH, data = b'', context = 'context'

    def __call__(self, obj, data, context):
        self.parser = obj
        self.logger = obj.logger
>       self.parse_er_data(data, context)
E       TypeError: parse_er_data() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

exchanges/protocols/mixins.py:113: TypeError
______________________________________________________________ ERROR at setup of TestMTSParser.test_get_update_type_cancel[1-False-6-1] _________
```

Here is the class that the error is referring to:

```
class Subparser:
    def __call__(self, obj, data, context):
        self.parser = obj
        self.logger = obj.logger
        self.parse_er_data(data, context)
```

Is this happening because `mts.get_subparser()(mts, b'', 'context)` is calling on `__call__`, which in turn has `parse_er_data(data, context)`, which only has 2 arguments?

If this is true then I don't understand this, because previously I had:

```
mts.get_subparser()(mts, b'')
```

and

```
self.parse_er_data(data)
```

And this worked fine with NO ERRORs, so why now is it creating errors???

Extra details:

Subparser.parse_er_data looks like this:

```
def parse_er_data(self, data):
    
    raise NotImplementedError("Should be reimplemented in subparser")
```

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `Subparser.parse_er_data(...)`?

Comment: sure, let me add

Comment: Is it because parse_er_data() is missing one arg? Because when I added an additional argument to it, I still got the same error!

Comment: Are you saying that `self.parse_er_data` is an instance of `Subparser`?  Are you sure of that?  Because I think the error message would be different if that were the case.  You're sure that `MTSParser` doesn't have an explicit `parse_er_data` method?

Answer (score 0):

The issue, I think, is that `parse_er_data()` takes two arguments - `self`, and `data`. When you call `self.parse_er_data(data, context)`, you are passing the function three arguments - you are passing it both `data` and `context` but you are also passing it `self`, `self` being the first argument you pass it because you are calling the function in method format. If you change `parse_er_data` to the following, it should fix your error:

```
def parse_er_data(self, data, context):
    raise NotImplementedError("Should be reimplemented in subparser")
```

Also, I'm not sure why you are passing in additional arguments to this function when you don't use them...

Comment: Thanks Zarquon, but I am still getting the error after changing it to parse_er_data(self,data,context). Though I do understand your point regarding 'self' being an argument because of the way it is used

Comment: Hmmmm.... It's still saying that `parse_er_data()` takes two positional arguments? That doesn't make any sense. Is it possible that there is some other `parse_er_data` function that the interpreter is calling? Also, have you tried calling the function with only two positional args like this: `self.parse_er_data(data)`? If that doesn't get you an error then I might try changing the name of function and trying three args again. If none of this helps then I am just as stumped as you are.

Comment: Yepp it works without any errors when I change it to self.parse_er_data(data). But I need 'context' to be passed into it as well, because there are dependencies on it! - any ideas how I can add it. Does this means that there is a parse_er_data() somewhere in the interpreter with the wrong number of args?

Comment: Oh, you just prepend and append your code blocks with this character: ` . And yes, this could mean that there is some other `parse_er_data()` function somewhere, but I don't know how that could be possible without you knowing about it, so I'm skeptical that that is what is happening. I'm a little stumped on what exactly the issue is, but there might be an easy, if slightly unelegant work around. Instead of passing in `context` as an argument, you could declare `context` to a be global variable using the `global` keyword and use the same keyword within `parse_er_data()` to access it.